# set password to not asked on login via the command line

Tags: lightdm, users, ubuntu-mate

how do i set the password settings of a user (named: interface) to not asked on login via the command line on ubuntuMATE?

i need to do this via the command line because the screen resolution on the raspberry pi is a very low 420x360 making doing it via the GUI impossible since it doesn't display fully.

Comment: not rasbien, UbuntuMATE 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a superuser, you can enable automatic login for yourself or for any other Ubuntu user by making some configuration changes in the custom.conf file as follows:

1. Connect to Raspberry through ssh or [VNC viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/).
2. Open the custom.conf file in the Nano editor through the following command:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
   ```

When you enter your password, the following file will open:

[image: screenshot of custom.conf]

In this file, the selected lines have been commented out. This means that in our file, the automatic login feature for user1 has been disabled.

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu MATE and LightDM:

Open the lightdm.conf file.

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

remove # on those lines: (lines marked as comment with # will be ignored by lightdm)

```
autologin-user=username
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

(replace username)

Also explained here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Setting_an_Automatic_Login

If your screen resolution is too small you can drag windows with Alt + Left Click.